# How to test classes depending on code only defined in header files?

Tags: c++, unit-testing

I'm getting started with unit testing in C++ and I'm trying to figure out the best practices. Today however I sort of hit a brick wall when writing code that uses [boost interprocess](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/interprocess.html), specifically file_mapping and mapped_region which are defined in headers only.

My general question is: How to test classes depending on code only defined in header files (i.e. Boost and STL)?

Example:
Let's say I create a class like this
MyClass.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <stddef>

namespace boost { namespace interprocess {
class mapped_region;
}}

class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(mapped_region& mapped_region);
    std::size_t get_size() const;

private:
    boost::interprocess::mapped_region& mapped_region_;
}
```

MyClass.cpp file:

```
#include "MyClass.h"
#include <boost/interprocess/mapped_region.hpp>

using namespace boost::interprocess;

MyClass::MyClass(mapped_region& mapped_region)
: mapped_region_(mapped_region) {}

std::size_t MyClass::get_size() const
{
    return mapped_region_.get_size();
}
```

How does one go about testing MyClass::get_size()? Since mapped_region implemented in the header file only it will create a object file that is basically independent on other object files (aka, no linking needed) and therefore creating a fake or mock object will not because it cannot be linked in.

The only way I can see working is to use #ifdefs in the .cpp and doing something like this in MyClass.cpp:

```
#ifdef RUN_UNITTEST
#include "my_fake_mapped_region.h"
#else
#include <boost/interprocess/mapped_region.hpp>
#endif
```

But this seem like a horrible hack and infects the production code with tests.

I guess one could use boost in the test code, but that would require the creation of files on disk and it would not technically be a unit test anymore, but a integration test? (Sorry if I'm wrong about the terminology).

I would really appreciate some insights on this matter.

Comment: I'm a bit lost on what your trying to test / testing methodology. If you want to unit test `MyClass::get_size()` feed your class vaild info and check if you get back the correct values. what's the issue?

Comment: To test the get_size method I need the mapped_region object, which is requires a file_mapping, which opens a file on disk. Normally I would create a fake object for mapping_region and use that in my test, but in this case, since mapping_region is header only that doesn't work. I don't want to create a file just for running the test. Hope that clears things up.

Comment: That approach can spell disaster. If boost::interprocess gets changed in some upcoming boost version and it has a bug or it behaves in a way that changes the `get_size();`, your test will never catch it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to create a typical abstraction layer is by wrapping the offending library behind a very thin layer that you inject into the constructor of the object that needs it.  You already understand that wrapping each and every boost function would turn using boost into using a difficult non-standard mess of wrappers.

And as you've discovered, you can't simply inherit the interface from the library as the declaration contains the implementation, because it's the implementation that's giving you problems.

The trick is recognizing you don't have to wrap every boost template.  You only have to wrap the ones that are giving you the "hard to set up" and "hard to test" problems.  `boost::interprocess` qualifies as one of those hard to test problems, so it deserves a wrapper.

Keep in mind that you should not be trying to test boost here.  Your unit test doesn't (and shouldn't) care if it sets up a real memory map or calls a fake one, as long as the call seems to have worked so your tests can proceed.  Nor do you need to test the wrappers you create, as long as they're so thin that you can easily verify they contain no logic.  For example, I wouldn't bother testing the `MyMemoryRegionWrapper::get_size()` method as visual inspection shows it simply returns the returned value.

Comment: I agree that in this exact example it might not make much sense to test the `get_size()` function as it is basically a proxy function. In a function that is responsible for creating the actual file by using `std::filebuf` (for example) the code is not a simple proxy, but actually does some stuff. One way to test this "in a normal" setting could be to create a mock object and check that specific calls are made in a specific order, but here the same problem arises.

Comment: Regarding `get_size()` , I was referring to the idea that you didn't have to test the proxy.  File access is another one of those hard-to-test problems that might require a wrapper so you can inject a mock.   In general, mocking templates will always be hard in C++ because interfaces are defined separate from implementations.